# Javascript java.lang.runtime.getRuntime.exec() not working; "java is not defined", importPackage not working

Tags: javascript, import, runtime, lang

I'm trying to execute a java program from within an HTML file using Javascript (specifically, the assignment is to activate an FTP server from an HTML interface, so I need to execute the FTPServer class from a function on my HTML page). I've been trying to use the following code to execute the "program" class which should simply print out "hello." The Chrome console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: java is not defined"

```
    var p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac program.java");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "working";
    var p2 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c java program");
    var stdInput = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
    var stdError = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(p2.getErrorStream()));
```

I've also tried doing Packages.java.lang.Runtime... to which I get the error "Packages is not defined." I've tried importing the java.lang package:

```
importPackage(java.lang);
```

but I get the same error, "Uncaught ReferenceError: importPackage is not defined"

Why isn't importPackage working, and how can I get Runtime to work?

Comment: If you're trying to do that in JavaScript code in an ordinary web page, it won't work. Java is simply not available like that. Your code would work (maybe) in Rhino, but then that wouldn't be code in an ordinary webpage and things like `document` wouldn't be there. I think you may have misunderstood the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do only makes sense in rhino.

According to [Rhino Migration Guide](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Rhino+Migration+Guide) you can try something like this:

```
var Runtime = Java.type("java.lang.Runtime");
```

and then run it with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac program.java");
```